# Single file uploads instead of multiple files in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a website using `asp.net mvc 4` where I can store data in MSSQL db & store uploaded image files in local storage. So far data is storing successfully but whenever I select multiple images to upload, it only uploads the first selected image only. Here are my codes,

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FlatManager(FlatMgt FlatTable, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var AddFlat = FlatTable.Flats;
                db.FlatInfoes.Add(AddFlat);
                db.SaveChanges();
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        int imageCount = 0;
                        string picName = FlatTable.Flats.flatno.ToString() + "-" + imageCount;
                        string picExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        if (picExt == ".jpg" || picExt == ".gif" || picExt == ".jpeg")
                        {
                            picExt = ".png";
                        }
                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), picName + picExt);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        imageCount++;
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                            byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TempData["add_fail"] = "Error! Wrong File Type(s)! Please Try Again.";
                        return RedirectToAction("FlatManager");
                    }
                }
                TempData["add_success"] = "Information Added Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("FlatManager");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["add_fail"] = "Error! Please Provide Valid Information.";
                return RedirectToAction("FlatManager");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FlatManager", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label> 
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files" id="file" style="width: 100%;" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
}
```

I can't find any error in my codes. How can I solve this problem? Will be really helpful if someone helps. Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually debugged that only one file is sent, or is the problem that you have `imageCount` inside your loop so every image file is saved with the number 0?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just put the `int imageCount = 0` line outside the loop & it worked. Your guess is right, it was saving with the same name so as a result images were replacing.